# Haskell - random (mkStdGen 0) - Why is it working without explicit type?

Tags: haskell

The type of the expression `random (mkStdGen  0)` is `Random a => (a, StdGen)`, so I tried:

```
System.Random> random (mkStdGen 0) :: (Int, StdGen)
(9106162675347844341,1346387765 2103410263)
System.Random> random (mkStdGen 0) :: (Double, StdGen)
(0.9871468153391151,1346387765 2103410263)
```

But, why does the following work?

```
System.Random> random (mkStdGen 0)
(9106162675347844341,1346387765 2103410263)
```

How was it able to "guess" a type in this case?

Comment: did you do this in ghci?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4):

> Ambiguities in the class `Num` are most common, so Haskell provides another way to resolve them—with a default declaration: `default (t1 , … , tn)` where n ≥ 0, and each `ti` must be a type for which `Num ti` holds. In situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type variable, `v`, is defaultable if:
>
> - `v` appears only in constraints of the form `C v`, where `C` is a class, and
> - at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, `Num` or a subclass of `Num`), and
> - all of these classes are defined in the `Prelude` or a standard library (Figures 6.2–6.3 show the numeric classes, and Figure 6.1 shows the classes defined in the `Prelude`.)
>
> Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable’s classes. It is a static error if no such type is found.
>
> Only one default declaration is permitted per module, and its effect is limited to that module. If no default declaration is given in a module then it assumed to be:
>
> ```
> default (Integer, Double)
> ```

This *almost* explains the behavior, except that the class `Random` in the constraint `Random a` is not a subclass of `Num` from the `Prelude`; to explain this, we must consult the [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules):

> At the GHCi prompt, or with GHC if the `-XExtendedDefaultRules` flag is given, the following additional differences apply:
>
> - Rule 2 above [ed. note: this is the third rule in our list above] is relaxed thus: All of the classes `Ci` are single-parameter type classes.
> - Rule 3 above [ed. note: this is the second rule in our list above] is relaxed this [sic]: At least one of the classes `Ci` is numeric, or is `Show`, `Eq`, or `Ord`.
> - The unit type `()` is added to the start of the standard list of types which are tried when doing type defaulting.

And now we're a bit closer to an explanation, except that it seems that the second bullet point *still* isn't satisfied: `Random` is neither numeric nor one of the three listed acceptable alternatives. BUT ghci implicitly adds a call to `print` for non-`IO` actions (and even for `IO` actions first tries adding a call to `print` to see if things will type-check, falling back on the non-`print`ing version only when that fails), and as a result we get an additional `Show a` constraint hidden in the type of our expression, and this finally explains why the defaulting rules may be used. Since there is no instance of `Random` for `()`, the default falls through to `Integer`.

Comment: I don't think GHCi tries to `print` `IO` actions. I think it first tries for `IO` and then falls back on printing. Test: write an orphan `instance Show (IO a) where show _ = error "You can't show IO, silly!"`. I've tried this, and IIRC it did not affect GHCi's treatment of `IO`.

Comment: @dfeuer It doesn't try to call `print` directly on the action, but rather `(>>= print)`. With your `Show` instance, try `let returnIO :: a -> IO a; returnIO = return in returnIO (returnIO ())`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your claim. Perhaps you should clarify in the answer.